# Riot.JS: immutable data structure causes unwanted rendering

Tags: redux, immutability, riot.js

I tried to manage my Riot app state with Redux but I noticed that when something changes in my model (a simple array of items), every elements rendered from this collection are re-rendered, even if the modification relates to one item.

[I reproduced the issue here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dA3Z0AsIpIInzj3ZZLg8)

With a mutable reducer there is no problem, in both cases I watch changes in the store to trigger view update (unnecessary with mutable data).

```
this.on('mount', () => {
  opts.store.subscribe(() => {
    this.update({
      items: opts.store.getState()
    })
  })
})
```

[image: gif demonstrating that DOM of my list is completely re-rendered]

I thought the virtual DOM check of Riot will only re-render changed parts of the DOM...

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `no-reorder` to loop:

```html
<li no-reorder each={ items } onclick={ toggle }>
  <span>{x}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, is there any limitations doing that?

Comment: @Freez Unfortunately, I don't know.

Comment: "In riot v2.3 to make the loops rendering more reliable the DOM nodes will be moved, inserted and removed always in sync with your data collections: this strategy will make the rendering slower compared to the previous 2.2 releases. To enable a faster rendering algorithm you can add the attribute no-reorder to the loop nodes."  from http://riotjs.com/guide/